# Checkout maven project from SCM: disconnect and merge

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

Whenever checking out Maven project from svn server in Eclipse, it creates a new folder like `maven.xxxxxxxxxxxx` under the target workspace. After specific time, it disconnected from SVN server.

My question is when the new checkout process is started again:- 
Can the next checking-out process merge to one of the existing folder `maven.xxxxxxxxxxxx`?

Any input would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly. This happens if something stops the import step. While I can not tell you wat exactly went wrong in your case, I can tell you how to solve it:

Rename the `maven.xxxxx`folder in your workspace to the real project name.

The select `File -> Import... -> Existing Maven Project` and choose the project folder. The project will appear in your workspace as maven project.

Depending on your eclipse configuration and plugins environment, you might also need to right-click on your new project and select `Team -> Share... -> SVN` (if there is a long list of options under `Team`, it is already correctly identifed as SVN project).

**Update**

If your `maven.xxxx` folder is empty, than you seem to have connection problems. Split the checkout and the import part:

- Switch to the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective, create the repository (if not already there). Can you browse the repository? If not, you have a connection problem (proxy?).
- Right click your SVN project and select -> Checkout...
- Select Check out as project in the workspace
- This checks out the project as simple resource project
- now back in the java perspective you can either delete the project and do an "Import existing Maven Project" or convert the project to a maven project using `right-click -> Configure -> Convert to Maven project` (exact command may vary with your m2e version).

If everything elese fails, try to checkout your project using TortoiseSVN (on Windows) or the commandline and doing "import -> existing maven project" afterwards.

Comment: No project appears when I import the folder using `Existing Maven Project`. :(

Comment: Did the checkout succeed? are there files inside the maven.xxx folder? If not, your can delete the folder. In that case I would suggest splitting checkout and import.

Comment: Checkout is not completed for every `mavan.xxx` folder. Pls suggest splitting checkout and import.

Comment: Your updated answer helped me a lot. Found connection speed of that way is better than normal `File > Import > Checkout Maven Project from SVN`. Finally the project is checked out successfully. :) Thanks!!